# Like an ordinary indexed image,in the figure’s colormap. The difference is that the matrix values are linearly

Tags: image, matlab, find, rgb, pixel

find pixels location that  have value/color =white

```
for i=1:row
    for j=1:colo
      if i==x    if the row of rgb image is the same of pixel location row


      end
    end
end
end
what's Wrong
```

Comment: What error are you getting, or what is this code doing that is not expected?

Comment: ok,is put just one white piont in object in rgb image,but i need put on all object area white point or white mask in rgb image

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use logical indexing.

For logical indexing to work, you need the mask (`bw2`) to be the same size as RGB.
Since RGB is 3D matrix, you need to duplicate `bw2` three times.

Example:

```
%Read sample image.
RGB = imread('autumn.tif');

%Build mask. 
bw2 = zeros(size(RGB, 1), size(RGB, 2));
bw2(1+(end-30)/2:(end+30)/2, 1+(end-30)/2:(end+30)/2) = 1;

%Convert bw2 mask to same dimensions as RGB
BW = logical(cat(3, bw2, bw2, bw2));

RGB(BW) = 255;

figure;imshow(RGB);
```

Result (just decoration):
[image]

---

In case you want to fix your `for` loops implementation, you can do it as follows:

```
[x, y] = find(bw2 == 1);
[row, colo, z]=size(RGB); %size of rgb image
for i=1:row
    for j=1:colo
        if any(i==x)    %if the row of rgb image is the same of pixel location row
            if any(j==y(i==x)) %if the colos of rgb image is the same of pixel loca colo
                RGB(i,j,1)=255; %set Red color channel to 255
                RGB(i,j,2)=255; %set Green color channel to 255
                RGB(i,j,3)=255; %set Blue color channel to 255
            end
        end
    end
end
```

---

Comment: The logic `if any(i==x) && any(j==y)` is wrong here, since `x` and `y` should be used in pair, i.e. `x(1)` only corresponds to `y(1)`, `x(2)` only corresponds to `y(2)` and so on. For example, when the user wants to make (1,1) and (2,2) to white, your logic will make (1,1),(1,2),(2,1) and (2,2) into white. The correct logic should be `if any(i==x) && any(j==y(i==x))`, where `j` is compared to those y coords having a x coord of `i`. I've tried to edit your answer but don't know why it didn't get through.

Comment: Thank you for finding a bug in my answer... I modified my post. (The reason the edit didn't get through is because it kind of "against author's intent"). The right way is to leave a comment. Thank you.

Comment: I'm sorry but I didn't have enough reputation to comment back then.

Comment: thank you very much Dear, I apologize for the delay in reply

Answer (score 1):

`[x, y] = find(bw2 == 1)`
`x` and `y` are arrays unless there is only one pixel is white.

However, `if i==x` and `if j==y` are comparing a single number with an array. This is wrong.

Comment: Thank you dear for clarification

Answer (score 1):

As Anthony pointed out, x and y are arrays so `i==x` and `j==y` won't work as intended. Furthermore `RGB(i,j)` only uses the first two dimensions, but RGB images have three dimensions. Lastly, from an optimization point of view, the for-loops are unnecessary.

```
%% Create some mock data. 
% Generate a black/white  image. 
bw2 = rand(10);
% Introduce some 1's in the BW image
bw2(1:5,1:5)=1; 
% Generate a RGB image. 
RGB = rand(10,10,3)*255; 

%% Do the math. 
% Build a mask from the bw2 image
bw_mask = bw2 == 1;
% Set RGB at bw_mask pixels to white. 
RGB2 = bsxfun(@plus, bw_mask*255, bsxfun(@times, RGB, ~bw_mask)); % MATLAB 2016a and earlier
RGB2 = bw_mask*255 + RGB .* ~bw_mask; % MATLAB 2016b and later.
```

Comment: thanks Dear for simple explain but the RGB2 = bsxfun(@plus, bw_mask*255, RGB .* ~bw_mask); Does not work in matlab R2015a

Comment: I think it should be: `RGB2 = bsxfun(@plus, bw_mask*255, bsxfun(@times, RGB, ~bw_mask)); % MATLAB 2016a and earlier`

Comment: Good catch! I'm running on MATLAB 2016b so I missed this one.